# Sort data using one field descending then ascending on a second field?

Tags: powershell, sorting

In a PowerShell script, I'd like to sort an array of custom object by one field descending then by another ascending.

However, the Sort-Object function only allows one sort specification (as far as I know).

How to sort using complex sort ?

In SQL I'd use `Order by Date ASC, SomeField DESC`. Is there an equivalent in PowerShell ?

To illustrate, here's a small repro:

```
$data = @(
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 2 ; SomeText = "a" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 2 ; SomeText = "b" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 2 ; SomeText = "c" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 3 ; SomeText = "d" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 3 ; SomeText = "e" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 3 ; SomeText = "f" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 1 ; SomeText = "g" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 1 ; SomeText = "h" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 1 ; SomeText = "i" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 0 ; SomeText = "j" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 0 ; SomeText = "k" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 0 ; SomeText = "l" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 0 ; SomeText = "m" }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 0 ; SomeText = "n" }
)

$data | Sort -Descending SomeInt, SomeText | Select SomeInt, SomeText
```

The output is

```
SomeInt SomeText
------- --------
      3 f       
      3 e       
      3 d       
      2 c       
      2 b       
      2 a       
      1 i       
      1 h       
      1 g       
      0 n       
      0 m       
      0 l       
      0 k       
      0 j
```

However, I'd like `SomeText` to be ordered ascending...

Comment: The help docs are your friend.  Check out _Example 5_ in the [Sort-Object help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6).

Comment: @boxdog: missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Applying the Sort order with a hash table seems to mangle the property order,

so you'll need a Select-Object to reestablish the proper order</s>

```
$data | Sort-Object -Property @{e="SomeInt";Descending=$True},
                              @{e="SomeText";Descending=$False}|
    Select-Object SomeInt,SomeText
```

Sample output:

```
SomeInt SomeText
------- --------
      3 d
      3 e
      3 f
      2 a
      2 b
      2 c
      1 g
      1 h
      1 i
      0 j
      0 k
      0 l
      0 m
      0 n
```

**EDIT: It's not `Sort-Object` which doesn't respect a given order, it's `New-Object`**

```
> New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeInt = 2 ; SomeText = "a" }

SomeText SomeInt
-------- -------
a              2

> New-Object PSObject -Property @{ SomeText = "a" ; SomeInt = 2 }

SomeText SomeInt
-------- -------
a              2
```

Comment: @mklement0 Right, I jumped to a wrong conclusion, I'm curious after what rules `New-Object` orders properties.

Comment: You're passing a hashtable literal to `New-Object`, so its the hashtable's lack of key ordering that's the problem. In PSv3+, you can use `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`, which seemingly also passes a hashtable, but in reality it's syntactic sugar for direct object construction that _does_ respect the key order. In v2, the only way to get predictable property ordering is by attaching the properties one by one with `Add-Member`.